# Чо означает путь к файлу начинающийся с ./?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Везде искал и не могу понять что означает путь начинающийся с ./ .
В webpack при подключении модуля
`import something from './some/path'`

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов как можно обращаться к файлам:

**1**: `/` - путь к корневой папки
Пример:
`import styles from '/dist/styles/main.min.css';`

**2**: `'./'` - путь относительно файла в котором мы находимся.
Пример:
`import store from './store.js';`

**3**: `'../'` - выходим из папки в которой находимся, т.е. путь на уровень выше.
Пример:
`import store from '../store.js';` - импортируем файл из уровня выше

**4**: `'react'` - путь к папке react в папке node_modules
Пример:
`import React from 'react';` - импортируем файл из node_modules/react

Подробнее можете почитать на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files)